# "Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file." message with a class deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, message

I have this message when i run my app :

> Unknown class KBCameraViewController in Interface Builder file.

I deleted this class and i have the message. I search the class in my project for search some references but nothing. The class didn't exist. If i add the class, the error didn't display at runtime.

i try to delete reference and the class but i got the message. It isn't normal that Interface Builder file have a error with a class that no longer exists.

I don't need this class and i want to delete it.

Comment: Your XIB is having class reference of KBCameraViewController. Check in the XIB.

Comment: Thanks you ! i have only one reference : in my storyboard and the error come there. Problem solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment of  Pooja M. Bohora
"Your XIB is having class reference of KBCameraViewController. Check in the XIB."

Thanks you ! I have only one reference : in my storyboard and the error come there. Problem solved !